# Git: Replace Core Folder

Tags: git

I had a critical issue in my project that I could not fix. So I went to GitHub and downloaded a previous version of the project as a new starting point. However of course this is not tracked in git so I started with

```
git init
```

then linked the new project folder to the previous `git remote` to try to get back into my repository.

However when I went to push the new version I got the error:

`[rejected] master -> master (non-fast-forward) hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind`

Comment: Is there a reason you did not use `git clone`?  `git init` is meant to create a *new* repository - you *can* use it to get back to a "normal" repo state, but it will take more manual work.

Comment: Or even better, you probably could have just checked out an old commit in your original repo.  Typically there is very little reason to create an entirely new clone unless your Git metadata was corrupted beyond repair.

Comment: @0x5453 Can you give me an example of how to do that

Comment: If you know the version you want to go back to, clone a new sandbox `git clone <remote_url>` and then just checkout the tag or branch name it corresponds to.

Comment: `git pull --rebase origin master`